# opengl-es 1.1 or 2.0 on an Android 2.3.3 AVD?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Should you be able to run an apk that uses opengl-es 1.1 or 2.0 on an Android 2.3.3 AVD? Or does the emulator not emulate opengl-es 1.1 + for 2.3.3 devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open GL will not run on Android emulator. You’ll need actual device to run it.

Comment: There is now support for Open GL ES, I think its only API level 17 + though, there are instructions on the android site under how to use the emulator they're the same as how to enable hardware acceleration to make the emulator run faster. I bought a second hand Samsung S2 and tested my app with 2.3.4.